# Processing events in QT OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

For example I painted some figure in QT using OpenGL. How can I process an event which I can generate on this figure (click or smth)?

Comment: are you using a QGLWidget?

Comment: @marco-a yes, QT 5.*

Answer (score 0):

The [QGLWidget tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/opengl-hellogl.html#mouse-handling) gives you a pretty good overview of mouse events handling. It boils down to  reimplementing `QWidget::mousePressEvent()` and `QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()`

```
void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
 {
     int dx = event->x();
     int dy = event->y();
     // do something
 }
```